# make manual pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I make pagination function but the result is still incorrect. The page I wanna show just 8 but the result showing till 9. So when I click number 9 shows nothing. This is my pagination code:

```
<?php if($current_page>1){ ?>                
        <nav class="pagination pagination-blue">
                    <a class="ajaxPage" href="<?=base_url()?>tracking/searchTiket?page=<?=($current_page-1)?>&&no_ticket=<?=$no_ticket?>&&s_month=<?=$month?>&&s_year=<?=$year?>">prev</a>
                    </nav>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php 
                $max = 5;
                if($current_page < $max)
                    $sp = 1;
                elseif ($current_page >= ($page_size - floor($max/2)) )
                    $sp = $page_size - $max + 1;
                elseif($current_page >= $max)
                    $sp = $current_page - floor($max/2);
                    for($i = $sp; $i<=($sp + $max -1); $i++){
                        if($i > $page_size)
                            continue;
                        if($current_page == $i)
                ?>        
        <nav class="pagination pagination-blue">
            <a class="ajaxPage" href="<?=base_url()?>tracking/searchTiket?page=<?=$i?>&&no_ticket=<?=$no_ticket?>&&s_month=<?=$month?>&&s_year=<?=$year?>"><?=floor($i)?></a></nav>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if(ceil($page_size)!=($current_page+1)){ ?>
        <nav class="pagination pagination-blue">
                <a class="ajaxPage" href="<?=base_url()?>tracking/searchTiket?page=<?=($current_page+1)?>&&no_ticket=<?=$no_ticket?>&&s_month=<?=$month?>&&s_year=<?=$year?>">next</a> </nav>
                <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not allowed to post on comments yet. 
I just wanna give you an idea. 
Try to check your query first if it gives the right amount of data you wish to retrieve.

Here's one of my oldest pagination design, gladly I kept it.

Here's the starting page: All working fine.
[image]

And here's the last page... as you can see, no result.
[image]

If your query is good, probably the problem is on your START & LIMIT.

I used this code I saw from the internet years ago: (sorry, I deleted original comments)

```
$tbl_name="your_table";
$adjacents = 10; // (10*2)+1 = 21 pages between next and prev

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$targetpage = "same_page.php";
$limit = 100; // rows to be displayed per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page)
{
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; // ** this caused the problem **
    $start = ($page + $limit) - 1; // ** this fixed the problem **
}
else{
    $start = 0;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit ";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
$prev = $page - 1;
$Next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //Prev button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$prev\" >« Latest&nbsp</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« Latest&nbsp</span>";  

    //pages
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">&nbsp$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$counter\" >&nbsp$counter</a>"; // just ignore search=$get, I believe you don't need this         
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$counter\" >$counter</a>";                    
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$lpm1\" >$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$lastpage\" >$lastpage</a>";      
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=1\" >1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=2\" >2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$counter\" >$counter</a>";                    
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$lpm1\" >$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$lastpage\" >$lastpage</a>";      
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=1\" >1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=2\" >2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {   
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$counter\" >$counter</a>";        


            }
        }
    }
    //Next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?search=$get&page=$Next\" >&nbspPrev »</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">&nbspPrev »</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";
}
?>

/**
*  YOUR TABLE 
*  GOES
*  HERE
*/ 

<?php echo $pagination;?>
```

As a result, last page displays the right data
[image]

I'm not good at CI, but I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I already check my query and that no problem, so I think my fault is in pagination logic @Jorz

Comment: I found another problem, I found my first page is not "1" but my first page is "0" so my pagination start from page 0. And the number result is like this
[1] [NEXT]. And when I click next or 1 the result is different from the first result. I don't know where the problem is, can you help me?
thanks, @jorz

Comment: check if your default $counter = 1.. it's your default start page (1)

Comment: I use you code but my query is not just like select * from tbl_name